# How to change the position of cells in a collection view tin constraints?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, cell

I have 4 cells within a collection view, but with the constraints added they appear near the upper right corner of the view.  Here is the code for those cells:

```
class TopHomeMenuBar: UIView, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {


lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemGreen
    cv.dataSource = self
    cv.delegate = self
    return cv
}()

let cellId = "cellId"

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)

    addSubview(collectionView)
    addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|[v0]|", views: collectionView)
    addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|[v0]|", views: collectionView)

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 4
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)

    cell.backgroundColor = .red

    return cell
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

}

Is there a way with those constraints to change the y coordinate of the cells so they appear near the bottom of the collection view?

Answer (score 0):

If the `UICollectionView` is static you can shift the cells to the bottom by losing the top constraint and giving it a constant height constraint and constraining it to the bottom. Here's how:

Modify this:

```
addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|[v0]|", views: collectionView)
addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|[v0]|", views: collectionView)
```

To this:

```
addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|[v0]|", views: collectionView)
addConstraintsWithFormat("V:[v0(100)]|", views: collectionView)
```